# Django, how i can add item corectly in my cart?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a online shop project, in my product detail view i can add to cart items and also this is a cart page which can increase or decrease item there too. the problem is that when i add one myb item in cart page it work like fibonacci sequence and it's add the new number if I have 3 item and use plus one it's gonna be 3+4=7 and if add one more it give me 7+8=15 item.
this is my `cart.py` :

def add(self, product, quantity=1):
product_id = str(product.id)

```
if product_id not in self.cart:
    self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 0}
else:
    self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity
self.save()
```

and this is `view.py`

```
def add_to_cat_view(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Products, id=product_id)
    form = AddToCartProductForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data
        quantity = cleaned_data['quantity']
        cart.add(product, quantity)

    return redirect('cart_detail')
```

and this is `cart_detail_view.html`

```
<form action="{% url 'cart_add' item.product_obj.id %}" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="quantity">
          <input type="number" class="quantity-input" name="quantity"
           id="qty-1" value="{{ item.quantity }}"min="1"> 
             {{item.product_update_quantity_form.inplace }}
             <button type="submit">update</button>
          </div>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the number to the quantity:

```
def set_quantity(self, product, quantity=1):
    product_id = f'{product.id}'
    if not quantity:
        self.cart.pop(product_id, False)  # remove from the cart
    else:
        item = self.cart.setdefault(product_id, {})
        item['quantity'] = quantity  # set quantity, not add
    self.save()
```

If you do not specify the quantity, then this will add a single item to the cart, you can also set it to `quantity=2` to immediately add two items to the cart if these are not yet in the cart. But if these are in the cart, it will set the quantity to the new quantity.